# Difference between all() and toArray() in Laravel 5

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

When I manage a collection that I need to convert to an array, I usually use `toArray()`. But I can also use `all()`. I'm not aware of the diference of those 2 function...

Anybody knows?

Comment: `all()` will return you **Eloquent Objects** where as `toArray()` will return you **Associative Arrays**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it's a collection of Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays with *toArray()*

```
    $col->toArray();
```

With all it will return an array of Eloquent models without converting them to arrays.

```
    $col->all();
```

> The toArray method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays:
>   [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray)

*all()* returns the items in the collection

```
/**
 * Get all of the items in the collection.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function all()
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

*toArray()* returns the items of the collection and converts them to arrays if Arrayable:

```
/**
 * Get the collection of items as a plain array.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray()
{
    return array_map(function ($value) {
        return $value instanceof Arrayable ? $value->toArray() : $value;
    }, $this->items);
}
```

For example: Grab all your users from database like this:

```
$users = User::all();
```

Then dump them each way and you will see difference:

```
dd($users->all());
```

And with toArray()

```
dd($users->toArray());
```

Comment: Are there any changes across versions 7-9? Is the same logic applied to nested objects?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll have to test it out and see.

Comment: @s3c Across versions 7-9 the functionality has not changed. The logic of `toArray()` also converts nested objects to arrays.